# Mysql query and $con

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$query = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname, username FROM users ORDER BY id desc";
$stmt = $con->prepare( $query );
$stmt->execute();
```

When I run the above code for my CRUD Single page Application I get a return on my webpage of:

> "Notice: Undefined variable: con in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\contactlist\read.php on line 7
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\contactlist\read.php on line 7"

How can I solve this?

Comment: By actually making sure `$con` is a valid reference to a DB object.

Comment: You are missing `$con = new PDO($db, $login, $password);`

Answer (score 2):

This message :

> Notice: Undefined variable: con in C:\xampp\htdocs\contactlist\read.php on line 7

It means that `$con` is not defined in your code. Did you do something like this before the preparation of your query as an example:

```
$con = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database");
if ($con->connect_errno) {
    echo "Connection failed to MySQL : (" . $con->connect_errno . ") " .    $con->connect_error;
}
```

Now, this error :

> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\contactlist\read.php on line 7"

means that you cannot call to a member function which is `prepare` if `$con` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a database connection prior to running any SQL queries

```
$con = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
```

You can find a beginning to end example on the PHP doc here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Answer (score 0):

Using PDO your $con may be defined like this

```
class db {
    public static function dbFactory($host, $dbase, $user, $pass) {
        $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbase", $user, $pass);
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);        
        return $pdo;
    }
}
$con = db::dbFactory('localhost','mydbname','myusername','mypassword');
```